# split empty data gives non-empty result

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
console.log($('.imgactive').data('tags'));  // empty

$('#tagsup').html("");
var arr = $('.imgactive').data('tags').split('***');
arr.forEach(function(el) {
    el.trim();
    var ob = $("<div class='tagup'>" + el + "</div>");
    ob.appendTo('#tagsup');
});
console.log($('#tagsup').html());
```

result:

```
<div class="tagup"></div>
```

I'm expecting `tagsup` to be empty because `data('tags')` of `imgactive` is empty.

Comment: are you using jQuery?

Comment: @Arun, yes, you can see obviously

Comment: by `empty`, do you mean `[]`? Just making sure

Comment: @bonaca well, there is no jQuery tag. And `$` could be anything, in theory. In the past Prototype (the library) was a major contender in using that variable, too.

Comment: @RahulDesai, empty means there is no any element inside

Comment: Please paste the log output of `$('.imgactive').data('tags')`

Comment: @RahulDesai, I cannot copy anything from console, the line is empty.

Comment: I think you should try doing that console.log after `$('#tagsup').html("");`, it seems thats what is making `arr` non-empty

Comment: @RahulDesai I tried and got empty line.

Comment: try console.log of `arr` before the `.forEach()`

Comment: @RahulDesai, result - `[""]`

Comment: Tag jQuery as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is correct and returns an empty result actually you create the element and feed it with empty result, so instead you can check if there's not data don't create the element

if you don't want to create the element at all you do something like that

```
if(el.length > 0){
    var ob = $("<div class='tagup'>" + el + "</div>");
        ob.appendTo('#tagsup');
    }
```

or you can do it before at all

```js
console.log($('.imgactive').data('tags'));  // empty

$('#tagsup').html("");
if($('.imgactive').data('tags')){
var arr = $('.imgactive').data('tags').split('***');

arr.forEach(function(el) {
    el.trim();
    var ob = $("<div class='tagup'>" + el + "</div>");
    ob.appendTo('#tagsup');
});
}
console.log($('#tagsup').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="imgactive">
</div>
```

Comment: where is element created, by which line?

Comment: @bonaca

  var ob = $("<div class='tagup'>" + el + "</div>");
    ob.appendTo('#tagsup');

Comment: that's already created the element without checking if there's el , it adds `null` to that div which is nothing

Comment: but this is `foreach` `el` and there is no any `el`

Answer (score 1):

That is because using the split function over an empty string retrieves an array with one empty element. You should check if tags is not empty before doing the split and the foreach function.

Comment: Shouldnt this be a comment?

Comment: 'split function over an empty string retrieves an array with one empty element` - that's like` 0/5 = 1` isn't it?

Comment: ''.split('***') => [''] , so you will have on iteration in your foreach loop